# How to insert a check mark using Python calendar?

Tags: python, calendar

I am going to write code that puts a check mark on a specific date with the Python calendar module, like in this image:

[image]

This is my code:

```py
import calendar
   
yy = 2021
mm = 10
   
# display the calendar
print(calendar.month(yy, mm))
```